# SAS call one program from a macro inside another program

Tags: sas

I have 2 sas programs, I am trying to call program 1  from a macro inside program 2. Program 1 uses a macro variable that I am setting in program 2.
But I get: `macro variable not resolved error`

```
test1.sas:

data test_&year1.;
a=1;
run;

test2.sas:
%macro x1(&year1);
...other code..;
%include test1.sas
%mend;

%x1(2019);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get rid of the & in %macro statement

```
%macro x1(year1);
```

[image]

```
filename FT15F001 temp;
parmcards4;
data test_&year1.;
   a=1;
   run;
;;;;

%macro x1(year1);
   %put NOTE: &=year1;
   %include FT15F001 / source2;
%mend;

%x1(2019);
```